# How do I get the type of internal card reader?

Tags: busybox

I have a Linux box which runs Busybox. There are two card reader build in. How can I get the type of the card readers?

I tried `lshw`, `hwinfo` and `lspci` but these commands are not implemented on Busybox.

---

Hello Stéphane Chazelas,

Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I tried it. However grep doesn't find anything.

```
# l `find /sys/devices -path '*/usb*/configuration'`
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0470300.ehci_v2/usb3/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0470400.ohci_v2/usb7/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0470500.ehci_v2/usb4/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0470600.ohci_v2/usb8/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0471000.xhci_v2/usb1/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0471000.xhci_v2/usb2/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0480300.ehci_v2/usb5/5-1/5-1.1/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0480300.ehci_v2/usb5/5-1/5-1.2/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0480300.ehci_v2/usb5/5-1/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0480300.ehci_v2/usb5/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0480400.ohci_v2/usb9/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0480500.ehci_v2/usb6/configuration
-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Oct  2 19:14 /sys/devices/rdb.3/f0480600.ohci_v2/usb10/configuration
# l `find /sys/devices -path '*/pci*/driver'`
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Oct  2 19:20 .
dr-xr-xr-x    4 root     root             0 Oct  2 19:20 ..
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct  2 19:31 devices
# l /proc/bus/pci/devices
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct  2 19:31 /proc/bus/pci/devices
```

Comment: What do you mean by _type_? Do you want the make and model of the device?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the vendor and model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Card readers are often USB devices. If so, you could do something like:

```
find /sys/devices -path '*/usb*/configuration' -exec \
   grep -lx 'CARD READER'  {} + | awk -F/ -vOFS=/ '{
     NF--
     getline idv < ($0 "/idVendor")
     getline idp < ($0 "/idProduct")
     getline v < ($0 "/manufacturer")
     getline p < ($0 "/product")
     print idv":"idp" "v" "p}'
```

To get vendor/product IDs and names (as reported by the kernel). That is look for USB devices whose *configuration* is set to *CARD READER* and extract the content of the `vendorID`, `productID`, `manufacturer` and `product` files located in the parent directory of the one containing the `configuration` file.

For PCI devices, this would catch at least the devices using the drivers below. busybox `find` doesn't support GNU `find`'s `-lname` predicate, so we'd need something like:

```
find /sys/devices -path '*/pci*/driver' -type l -exec readlink {} \; -print |
  awk -F/ -v OFS=/ '
    BEGIN{d["cb710"]d["r592"]d["r852"]d["rts5208"]d["rtsx_pci"]}
    $NF in d {
      getline
      NF--
      getline v < ($0 "/vendor")
      getline p < ($0 "/device")
      print substr(v, 3) ":" substr(p, 3)
    }'
```

There's no *configuration* file that we can use this time to determine the class of device (actually, there is a `class` file for the PCI device class, but I can see it being 0xff00 (Misc) for a Realtek device here, there is no PCI device class dedicate to "card readers" so we can't rely on it). So instead we look for `drivers` symlinks that point to any of the drivers known to be drivers for PCI card readers, and get the vendor/product IDs in paths relative to that.

A simpler approach is to use `/proc/bus/pci/devices`:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{d["cb710"]d["r592"]d["r852"]d["rts5208"]d["rtsx_pci"]}
  $NF in d {print substr($2, 1, 4) ":" substr($2, 5)}
' < /proc/bus/pci/devices
```